# What is the difference between "|" and "+"?

Tags: python, addition

I have been doing codewars challenges recently and stumbled across this: using the pipe symbol to add two items. I tried this in my python environment and am curious as to what this does and how this is different than just the + symbol.

```
print(5 | 2)
```

This of course outputs to 7. In the codewars problem I was looking at, one of the solutions used this to add two sets together. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`|`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) is a bitwise OR. In your example, it happens that:

```
0101
0010 |
---
0111
```

which is 7 in binary.

If you to calculate, for example, `5 | 9`. you'll get 13, and not 14, since `|` is NOT `+`.

Side note: If you're applying `|` to two numbers that their bitwise AND returns 0, then the addition and the bitwise OR returns the same result.

In the case of 2 and 5, `2 & 5 = 0`, so `+` and `|` returns the same result.

Comment: Worth noting this behavior is also what was going on with the sets in the mentioned codewars problem. E.g. `{1,2} | {3} == {1,2,3}`